# How to set up Firefox and Internet explorer when I use them to debug my html pages on local host?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm creating some web pages using ASP.NET MVC (VS as IDE, C# as language).

When I want to see real design of my page as it will be displayed to user I run using ASP.NET Development server on localhost and display the page in IE and Firefox.

Both IE and Firefox are driving my crazy... I have swiched off caching on both of them but they still keep displaying old versions of my web page. I suspect that they do not cache the html but they stil cache CSS file. So I got old versions and I'm trying to find bug in my code that is not there.

What can I do to make them display current page ? Without caching anything?

Comment: That is exactly what I do!! It is not about VS or Development server. It is about the browsers. They do unwanted caching.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio to run the solution, Ctrl+F5 in browser to refresh the page.

Comment: I did not press Ctrl+F5 but I cliked refresh button. I guess there is no difference.

Comment: Use Fiddler to see what's actually coming down from the test server. Select the Rules > Performance > Disable Caching option.

Answer (score 2):

Stop the asp.net web development server from the system tray and then again start debugging your application